# Get objects locked by thread

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

Is there a way in Java to get the list of objects on which a thread holds lock on ? I came across a method holdsLock(Object object) , but that requires you to pass the object.

Comment: Do not think so. At least no trivially.

Comment: I did some Googling and found `ThreadInfo`. I'm not sure how it works, as I've never used it, but it could be useful to you. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadInfo.html